# Unreproducible UWP App Crash Exception stowed_exception 80131500 In Windows Store Certification Process

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-store

I recently unable to get my UWP application through the certification multiple times. 
The certification team always tell me that it crash on startup / launch.
I'm not able to reproduce the crash myself even I have the stack trace.
If anyone face similar problem or any idea I can move forward, that will be great.

Things I tried but unable to reproduce the crash:

- Run Windows App Cert Kit, pass without crash or problem.
- Run the app in release mode with .NET native tool chain enabled.
- Install and run the package that get upload to Windows Store.
- Generate a side loaded app and install it on another non-development
  Windows 10 device.

The crash stack that get recorded are as follow

```
appname::app onlaunched()
stowed_exception 80131500: stowed_exception

combase.dll    RoOriginateLanguageException() error.cpp:1504
System.Private.Interop    System::Runtime::InteropServices::ExceptionHelpers OriginateLanguageException() ExceptionHelpers.cs:113
System.Private.Interop    System::Runtime::InteropServices::ExceptionHelpers GetHRForExceptionWithErrorPropogationNoThrow() ExceptionHelpers.cs:219
System.Private.Interop    System::Runtime::InteropServices::McgMarshal GetHRForExceptionWinRT() McgMarshal.cs:1239
appname.UniversalWindows.McgInterop.dll    __Interop::ReverseComStubs.Stub_12_System __Canon_$catch$0() SharedStubs.g.cs:11147
mrt100_app.dll    RhpCallCatchFunclet2() exceptionhandling.asm:438
mrt100_app.dll    System::Runtime::EH DispatchEx() ExceptionHandling.cs:683
mrt100_app.dll    System::Runtime::EH RhThrowEx() ExceptionHandling.cs:552
mrt100_app.dll    RhpThrowEx2() exceptionhandling.asm:198
System.Private.Interop    System::Runtime::InteropServices::McgMarshal ThrowOnExternalCallFailed() McgMarshal.cs:1267
appname.UniversalWindows.McgInterop.dll    __Interop::ComCallHelpers Call() SharedStubs.g.cs:8527
appname.UniversalWindows.McgInterop.dll    Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::IFrame__Impl::Stubs Navigate() ImplTypes.g.cs:158360
appname.UniversalWindows.McgInterop.dll    Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Frame Navigate() SafeTypes.g.cs:44489
appname.UniversalWindows.exe    appname::App OnLaunched() App.xaml.cs:76
System.Private.Threading    System::Progress$1_$89_System::VoidValueTypeParameter_.System.IProgress_T_ Report() SafeTypes.g.cs:23264
appname.UniversalWindows.McgInterop.dll    __Interop::ReverseComStubs.Stub_12_System __Canon_() SharedStubs.g.cs:11130
appname.UniversalWindows.McgInterop.dll    Windows::UI::Xaml::IApplicationOverrides__Impl::Vtbl OnLaunched__n() ImplTypes.g.cs:138287
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll    DirectUI::FrameworkApplicationGenerated OnLaunchedProtected() frameworkapplication.g.cpp:502
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll    DirectUI::FrameworkView OnActivated() frameworkview_partial.cpp:267
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll    Microsoft::WRL::Details::DelegateArgTraits_long (__cdecl Windows::Foundation::ITypedEventHandler_impl_Windows::Foundation::Internal::AggregateType_Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow *,Windows::UI::Core::ICoreWindow *_,IInspectable *_ *)() event.h:245
Microsoft::WRL::InvokeTraits_-2_::InvokeDelegates__lambda_3ad0adb09957fd62cbc86618ebbeb8fa_,Windows::Foundation::ITypedEventHandler_Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView *,Windows::ApplicationModel::Activation IActivatedEventArgs *_ _() internalevent.h:119
twinapi.appcore.dll    Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView Activate() coreapplicationview.cpp:545
rpcrt4.dll    Invoke() invoke.asm:183
rpcrt4.dll    Ndr64StubWorker() srvcall.cxx:392
rpcrt4.dll    NdrStubCall3() srvwrap.cxx:166
combase.dll    CStdStubBuffer_Invoke() stub.cxx:1446
rpcrt4.dll    CStdStubBuffer_Invoke() ndrfwds.cxx:182
combase.dll    ObjectMethodExceptionHandlingAction__lambda_c9f3956a20c9da92a64affc24fdd69ec_ _() excepn.hxx:87
combase.dll    DefaultStubInvoke() channelb.cxx:1452
combase.dll    SyncServerCall StubInvoke() servercall.hpp:826
combase.dll    ServerCall ContextInvoke() ctxchnl.cxx:1418
combase.dll    ASTAInvokeInApartment() applicationsta.cpp:470
combase.dll    AppInvoke() channelb.cxx:1182
combase.dll    ComInvokeWithLockAndIPID() channelb.cxx:2290
combase.dll    ThreadDispatch() chancont.cxx:416
combase.dll    ModernSTAState HandleMessage() modernsta.cpp:472
combase.dll    ModernSTAWaitContext HandlePriorityEventsFromMessagePump() modernsta.cpp:1550
Windows.UI.dll    Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher ProcessMessage() dispatcher.cpp:339
Windows.UI.dll    Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher WaitAndProcessMessagesInternal() dispatcher.cpp:1953
Windows.UI.dll    Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher WaitAndProcessMessages() dispatcher.cpp:461
twinapi.appcore.dll    _lambda_643db08282a766b00cec20194396f531_ operator() coreapplicationviewagilecontainer.cpp:1145
SHCore.dll    _WrapperThreadProc() thread.cpp:321
ntdll.dll    RtlUserThreadStart() rtlstrt.c:1152
```

This is on my App.cs line 76 if it is relevant.

```
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(InitializePage), e.Arguments);
```

The app have went through countless of submission in Windows Store without problem previously, this I have totally no idea what happen now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, .NET native team help me resolve this issue.
It was the app is too big to compile with 32bit compiler and some time run out of memory.
Even if it compile success, it may have random crash.
Adding true to a PropertyGroup in project help resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you explain where you add ```true``` plz

Comment: Ok, found out in your blog: "We have a 64 bit compiler available that can operate with more memory. Can you try to add <Use64BitCompiler>true</Use64BitCompiler> to a PropertyGroup in your main CSPROJ file?"

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, your app probably works differently on differently configured PCs, so it could be language settings or regional settings or something similar that is necessary to be set to some values to make the app crash.

Unfortunately UWP stacktrace comes from the compiled application which makes it useless in finding the cause in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have tested a few region and language but unable to duplicate the crash as well, including US-en, JP-jp, MY-en. Just email the certification team, hopefully they can answer what region and language they are actually using.